# Data mismatch in entity framework table MVC and API

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, api

I have table in my sql created using entity framework code first below:

[image: CustomerModelsTable]

Notice the ID of every data is not '0', but when i use api to get data it returning data with ID as '0'

[image: CustomersAPI]

here is my mapper code

```
public MappingProfile()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerModel, CustomerDto>().ForMember(c => c.ID, opt => opt.Ignore());
            Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerDto, CustomerModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<MoviesModel, MovieDto>().ForMember(m => m.ID, opt => opt.Ignore());
            Mapper.CreateMap<MovieDto, MoviesModel>();
        }
```

Comment: Can you add some code? The entity class, the access data and controller's method.

Comment: `0` is default value for `int` or other numeric values. So probably you just don't map `ID` from entity to `ID` in viewModel. You need to provide code from your API to tell what exactly is wrong.

Comment: ```public IEnumerable<CustomerDto> Customers()
        {
            return _Context.Customers.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<CustomerModel, CustomerDto>);
        } ```

Comment: better update your question with provided above code and also add Mapper configuration. Because still looks like mapper problems

Answer (score 0):

So from your mapper configs you are ignoring `ID` value, as result it returns default value (`0`).

```
     Mapper.CreateMap<CustomerModel, CustomerDto>().ForMember(c => c.ID, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Update your mapper settings to map `ID` also if you want that value.